# How to make only the child of a cardview clickable, and not the whole cardview itself?

Tags: android, xml

Here's the layout of the cardview in context:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:textColor="@color/md_teal_900"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_download" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want only the icon (imageview) to be clickable. This cardview is part of a recyclerview, and I can only make the whole card responsive to click, whereas I want only the imageview to be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do @Michele Lacorte's answer with onClick() method and then

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
image.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I don't want the title to be clickable at all, just the imageview. Isn't that a change I'll have to make in XML itself?

Answer (score 0):

Set `OnClickListener` to `ImageView`, here an example:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do operation
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you using `onClick()` method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

        //Add this case to your switch
        case R.id.icon:

           //Do operation

        break;
    }
}
```

And as @vspallas says do not forget to add `Listener`

```
image.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I'm currently using an overriding OnClick() function to listen to clicks. Where do I add this? In the constructor of viewholder?

Comment: Where do I set the onclicklistener like you initially showed? I'm unable to do it in onClick. The whole card responds to the click, not just the imageview. I want only imageview to be clickable.

Comment: I don't want the title to be clickable at all. Isn't that a change I'll have to make in XML itself?

Comment: Where to get the instance of ImageView from the layout, like first code